# add two arrays together, maintain indexes

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays which I want to join together.

I want to preserve the indexes.

First Array (start times)

```
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 08:00:00"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "28"
        ["start_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-26 18:00:00"
      }
    }
```

Second Array (end times)

```
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "15"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-06-24 17:00:59"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["ID"]=>
        string(2) "28"
        ["end_time"]=>
        string(19) "2012-07-26 22:00:59"
      }
    }
```

If I run;

```
    $merge[0] = $a[0] + $b[0];

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($merge);
    echo '</pre>';
```

I get;

```
   array(1) {
     [0]=>
     array(3) {
       ["ID"]=>
       string(2) "15"
       ["start_time"]=>
       string(19) "2012-06-24 08:00:00"
       ["end_time"]=>
       string(19) "2012-06-24 17:00:59"
     }
   }
```

How do I continue this trend?  I can only figure out how to target one index ( [0] ) at a time, I know a foreach loop is required to finish it off but unsure how to write it.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
{
  $merge[$i] = $a[$i] + $b[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `array_merge()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Hope it helps.

Comment: array_merge doesn't achieve what I need with preserving the keys

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right. It's because you use numeric keys. It works if you use textual keys.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach loop will look like this.

```
$merge = array();
for($i =0; $i<count($a); $i++)
   $merge[$i] = $a[$i] + $b[$i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1, $array2, $result = array();
foreach($array1 as $ind => $item)
    $result[$ind] = array( 
        'ID' => $item['ID'], 
        'start_time' => $item['start_time'], 
        'end_time' => $array2[$ind]['end_time']
    );
```